# gitbook template render error unknown block tag: static

Tags: gitbook

in my markdown file has these lines:

````
```python
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/xxx.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'js/xxx.js' %}"> </script>
```
````

however, gitbook get error, like:

> Template render error: (D:\my\django-toturial\template_base.md) [Line 29, Column 15]
>     unknown block tag: static (In file 'template_base.md')

why gitbook reserve `static` as a tag in my markdown files.，how to resolve this problme.

Answer (score 1):

I think it conflicts with templating used by Gitbook
https://toolchain.gitbook.com/templating/

To fix this you can use {% raw %} {% endraw %} between "{% static 'js/xxx.js' %}"